# How to get phone number or sim card information use android studio?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

How to get phone number or sim card information use android studio? (simcard 1 or 2)

I have used this code:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phone_number.setText(tMgr.getLine1Number());
```

And I've also added permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

But all the gadgets that I apply fail to get phone number or always generate a null value.

And this is the build.gradle I use:

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   //noinspection GradleCompatible
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
   //noinspection GradleCompatible
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

   //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
}
```

Comment: I think you need to request this permission on runtime, since its protection level is dangerous according to documentation (depends on which android version device that you use runs on)

Comment: it returns null cause it unavailable and the case is same on most cases, So, if you need to perform operations according to the sim(other than calling), then you should use `getSimSerialNumber()`

Comment: @x0r how to create permissions at runtime you mean?

Comment: @Sam. how to use getSimSerialNumber()?

Comment: `TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();`

Comment: `TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();`

Comment: @Sam. after getting sim serial number how to get his phone number too? I always get a null value when using this code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reliable way to get the phone number from the SIM card. The TelephonyManager reads the phone number from SIM card but its upto the Telecom operators to add this information in the SIM card.

Most of the Telecom operators don't add this information in SIM card hence its not reliable enough.

There is a way to use Google-Play-Service to get the phone number, but it also doesn't gurantee 100% to return the phone number. You can do it as follows.

Add following dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
}
```

Create two constants in `MainActivity.java`:

```
private static final int PHONE_NUMBER_HINT = 100;
private final int PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 200;
```

In `onclick` of your Button add following:

```
final HintRequest hintRequest =
  new HintRequest.Builder().setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true).build();

try {
  final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient =
    new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this).addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API).build();

  final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
    Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(googleApiClient, hintRequest);

  startIntentSenderForResult(
    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
    PHONE_NUMBER_HINT,
    null,
    0,
    0,
    0
  );
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Add onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PHONE_NUMBER_HINT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
        final String phoneNumber = credential.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, your code is not running on me, I also do not understand, please help me

Comment: cannot compile, when runing in emulator or real phone

Comment: @dyantb Have you updated your app level build.gradle?

Comment: @dyantb Just clean and rebuild. Ensure you have internet connection to download the libraries. You are getting the compilation error because libraries are not downloaded correctly

Comment: Your code is successful, but why every one appears only 1 phone number? My phone uses 2 sim cards, and i have 4 different sim cards and exchangeable, but that always appear only one of the sim card, although the sim card is not installed. (example: 1.provider A = 3G, 2.provider B = 4G, 3.provider C = 4G, 4.provider D = 4G and always appear is provider a)

Comment: @dyantb We don't have control over the numbers shown to the user. Its some hidden mechanism used by google to predict it. Depending on their profile created by google this number is shown. As I said there is no guaranteed way to achieve this, all you can do is best case scenario

Comment: the code you mean above works on several different mobile phones, but not on my phone. how to display her phone number without a popup like that?

Comment: Yes. They best way to get it without popup is `msisdn = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();` but it also has limitation as I have mentioned in the answer. There is no way you can gurantee that you will ge the MSISDN with 100% success rate.

Comment: Thanks sagar, i'm still confused as to why apps like social media or online stores can get their user's phone number. And this will bother me continuously.

Comment: @dyantb Are they working with your Phone + SIM configuration? Even Whatsapp cannot detect the phone number (if its being used for first time) on all the devices. Its always best case approach

Comment: Yes, I want to send the activation code via sms gateway without register and saves the user activity of the app including the phone number.
you can know it from where (about Whatsapp cannot detect the phone number)?

Comment: @dyantb About Whatsapp: I tried on few test phone + SIM card (where the telecom operator didn't configure the phone number) it asked me to enter the phone number manually.

Comment: it is working for me but how to get second sim slot number also I appreciate your answer ...help me

Comment: @bugfreerammohan You can check out [createForSubscriptionId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#createForSubscriptionId(int)) . Pass in the subscription Id and you will get the TelephonyManager for that ID. once you have it, you can use `getLine1Number()` to get respective number

Comment: in some of the devices, I am getting both numbers to thank you so much

Comment: is there any way to give numbers without dialog?

Comment: Thanks It's Work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This are few methods you can use:

```
mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String countryiso=mTelephonyMgr.getSimCountryIso();

String simOperator=mTelephonyMgr.getSimOperator();

String  simOperatorName=mTelephonyMgr.getSimOperatorName();

String  simSerialNo=mTelephonyMgr.getSimSerialNumber();

int     simState=mTelephonyMgr.getSimState();

String  subscriberID=mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
```

***Edit***

```
  String mPhoneNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

for more,[visit here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager?hl=de)

This Permission is also necessary.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this code is the same as the one I use, but the phone number I want remains null

Comment: this code is the same as the one I use and the phone number I want remains null

Comment: please check from beginning,i made a few changes in beginning,and i checked it on my device,it returns proper output,and as far as i know,that number,is provided by your sim operator.if the operator is not returning that info,you will always get null. each operator has different mono poly. @dyantb

Comment: I've adjusted all the code with you, and keep it null,
for this code (mAppContext) I have an error?
so the problem is in the provider?
how applications like facebook, alibaba, and other online stores deal with it?

Comment: @dyantb you can replace mAppContext with `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: I always get a null value when using this code. how to get phone number in simcard? please help me

Comment: I am still confused why applications such as social media or online shop can get the phone number usernya